# R / Tidyverse: Ordering factors within group with duplicate labels and plotting using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to plot a graph with ggplot where I facet on one variable, and make two plots (one for each variable showing a value (x) for a category (y), where y is plotted in descending order with respect to X within each group. The issue here is that in each group, the same y label exists and this seems to mess up the factor levels.

Setting up the data:

```
dummy_data <- tibble(
  
  y_var = c('v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v2', 'v6', 'v7', 'v4', 'v7'),
  x_var = c(0.0629, 0.0631, 0.0654, 0.0657, 0.0676, 0.0693, 0.0707, 0.0728, 0.0733, 0.0868),
  group_var = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B")
  
) %>% 
  group_by(group_var) %>% # group by the grouping variable
  arrange(x_var, .by_group = TRUE) %>% # arrange the rows by x_var, within each group
  mutate(y_var = factor(y_var, levels = y_var)) # change the y variable to a factor to retain order when plotting

dummy_data %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = x_var, y = y_var, color = group_var), size = 5) +
  facet_wrap(~group_var, scales = 'free', dir = 'v')
```

The output, shown below, is not ordered as desired.

[image]

This can be rectified by making all `y_var` values unique (adding group name to the value), however this is not desirable because this changes y axis labels (shown below)

```
dummy_data %>%
  mutate(y_var = str_c(y_var, group_var),
         y_var = factor(y_var, levels = y_var)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = x_var, y = y_var, color = group_var), size = 5) +
  facet_wrap(~group_var, scales = 'free', dir = 'v')
```

[image]

I would like to produce the second graph, without having to change the value of all `y_var`. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if there is a factor value for group B that does not exist in group A? For example V3 and V5 do not exist for group A, what dictates where they should be displayed for group B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tidytext::reorder_within()` does something similar, and in combination with `tidytext::scale_y_reordered()` helps with tidying the output to look like your goal.

```
library(tidytext)

dummy_data %>%
  mutate(y_var = reorder_within(y_var,  x_var, group_var)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = x_var, y = y_var, color = group_var), size = 5) +
  scale_y_reordered() +
  facet_wrap(~group_var, scales = 'free', dir = 'v')
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.